# Cumulative Products in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data with times (column t) and values (column v). I want to create a new column, call it p, which is the product of all v's from t=0 to the current row's t value. The row_cumsum() can do this for addition but I need a product.

I tried using extend  = v∗(,1,1), but kusto doesn’t recognize the p column in prev() because it is being created.

If the input is:

datatable(t:int, v:int)

```
            1, 1
            2, 1
            3, 2
            4, 3
            5, 3
            6, 2
```

I want the output to be:

datatable(t:int, v: int, p:int)

```
            1, 1, 1
            2, 1, 1
            3, 2, 2
            4, 3, 6
            5, 3, 18
            6, 2, 36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize log10() and row_cumsum() (cumulative sum):

```
datatable(t:int, v:int)
[
            1, 1,
            2, 1,
            3, 2,
            4, 3,
            5, 3,
            6, 2,
]
| order by t asc
| extend l = log10(v)
| extend cumsum = row_cumsum(l)
| project t, v, p=exp10(cumsum)
```